# Should I pre-book/prepay for activities before landing in Bali?

Tags: planning, bali, pre-pay

I am looking into several packages Tours like Sunrise Treking in Mt. Badur and Rafting in River.

Should I pre book them via website or should I book them day before the event or on the spot?

Which option will be better (better if cheaper)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in high traffic tourist areas, booking in advance reduce the stress of missing out the activity and/or wait in line for attractions; not really to save some money.

I tend to book in advance 1 or 2 attractions when I travel, and leave the others to decide on the spot.

For example, I am going to Barcelona and Sevilla in a couple of weeks, and I will book and buy tickets in advance for a couple of museums and attractions; and leave the other "minor" attractions to be handled on site depending on our mood.

Answer (score 1):

The sunrise tekking can be popular so advance booking is a good idea.  Rafting you can book after arrival unless you want a specific departure with a specific company.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will book sunrise trekking before Bali tour :)